# Weird bug react redux drive me crazy

Tags: reactjs, redux

Today i'm facing a bug who drives me crazy ! i'm using react with redux , never see a bug like that before. The problem is the "second parameters" of my dispatched function with redux always return me ALL THE REDUX STATE , all the others parameters are working and return me what they must return ! EXCEPT THE 2ND who always return all the the state ? what kind of sorcery is that

```
this.props.sendPushNotification(); // even with empty parameters return the second parameters with all the redux state


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({


  sendPushNotification: dispatch.notifications.sendPushNotification,

});



// my redux function  

async sendPushNotification (token, title , body , data) {
    
    
    console.log(token) // return undefined
    
    console.log(title) // ALWAYS RETURN ALL THE STATE / PROPS FROM REDUX EVEN IF THERE IS NO PARAMETERS 

console.log(body) // return undefined
console.log(data) // return undefined
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Why does this not throw: `sendPushNotification: dispatch.notifications.sendPushNotification`? That should definitely throw an exception when try to execute `dispatch.notifications.sendPushNotification()` as a function.

Comment: it's not throwing anything ?

Comment: and why it should throw an exception ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your current `mapDispatch` code is very wrong.

First, per our docs, [you should be using the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch` instead of the function form](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object):

```js
const mapDispatch = {
  sendPushNotification: notifications.sendPushNotification,
}
```

Second, if you *are* going to write `mapDispatch` as a function, it's now up to you to take the `dispatch` argument that was passed in, and use it to create new actions that dispatch when called:

```js
const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({
  sendPushNotification: (...args) => dispatch(notifications.sendPushNotification(...args))
})
```

Third... I have no idea why you're even writing `dispatch.notifications.sendPushNotification`.  The store's `dispatch` method shouldn't have any nested fields on it, so that seems like it should be breaking out of the box.

Finally, as for the "getting all the props from the Redux store passed in" part... I can only assume that your function is being interpreted as a thunk somehow, and thus it's having `getState` passed in as the second arg.

But really, the problem here is your `mapDispatch` code is wrong.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> it's not throwing anything

Yes it definitely is, why would you post code in your question that doesn't work?

> and why it should throw an exception?

See below (`Cannot read property 'sendPushNotification' of undefined"`):

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {};

const reducer = (state) => state;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  sendPushNotification:
    dispatch.notifications.sendPushNotification,
});
const App = connect(
  undefined,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(()=>'hi');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```